# How to generate a name with unique ID from infoPath form to Sharepoint Library? C#

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint, infopath2010

I have made a submit button with c# code that submits from infopath form to SharePoint library. In infopath form I have a field and you have to type name. Name must be always the same `john` How can i make after name to generate a unique number for each name that is typed I.E, I add a name as following: `john` the code should generate an ID, finally name will be added as `john 001`,`john 002`, `john 003` etc. 
My infopath form:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15WJ5.jpg)

My code for submit in c#:

```
XPathNavigator root = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator();

// Generate a name for the form to be saved in SharePoint
string formName =  Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

// Set the name of the form on the data connection
root.SelectSingleNode(
   "//my:formName ", NamespaceManager).SetValue(formName);

// Submit the form to SharePoint
DataConnection spConn =
DataConnections["SharePoint Library Submit"];
spConn.Execute();
 e.CancelableArgs.Cancel = false;
```

How can i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string formName = "Kerkesa" + random();
i was looking for this

And on the random() function there is a GUID GENERATOR